# Are Daenerys dragons the only dragons in the seven kingdoms?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

From the beginning of *Game of Thrones* until now, we have only seen 3 dragons.

Is there a chance to see other and bigger ones?

Comment: Well given that for the past 6 seasons they have repeatedly emphasized that Dragons were extinct, Daenerys brought them back to life, the chances are no, you wont! The trio seem to be the only Dragons alive. There's a fan theory however that there is an ice dragons residing beneath the wall so who knows

Comment: If however, you are interested in Dragons that have existed till now in Westeros, [See my previous answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134338/54887)

Comment: Well, there was a poster for the Seventh season where a White Walker was riding a White dragon (people assume it is a White Walker Ice Dragon). Now we do not know if this will happen at all, or if one of the dragons die and becomes that, or if he already exists and he will show up eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been a repeated plot point of the series (and books) every since the beginning. **Dragons are believed to be extinct for about 250 to 300 years.**

Dragon eggs have still been around (though they are incredibly rare). However, since no one has so far been able to have the eggs hatch (until Danaerys), the eggs are believed to be nothing but a souvenir.

---

The story starts at a time of relative peace (with Robert Baratheon on the throne). It has been many generations since the last dragon was seen. The same is true of white walkers and even magic in general (for most people).

It has been long enough that people have started believing that white walkers are a myth, and have never really existed.

However, the Long Night (the big war between humans and white walkers) was over a thousand years ago. Comparatively, the dragons have not been extinct for long enough that people doubt their existence. It has been between 250-300 years that dragons were last seen, as Aegon the Conqueror (who united Westeros and started the Targaryen dynasty that was only overthrown by Robert Baratheon's rebellion some 20 years before the story begins) used dragons to conquer Westeros 300 years ago.

As addressed in S07E01 (not a real spoiler), the maesters have tasked themselves with keeping the history books of Westeros.
Especially since Targaryens still ruled Westeros less than a generation ago; it stands to reason that both the maesters and the Targaryens have kept the memory of dragons alive. It is the sigil of House Targaryen, after all.

The Targaryen dragons were all but killed in a war that broke out between the Targaryens themselves (the name of this war currently eludes me). It wasn't long before the last dragon was reported to die, and no dragons have been seen since.

> ***edit** I feel I may have misstated here. The war between Targaryens did not kill all the dragons, but a considerable amount of them (> 66%) died during the war. The remaining dragons died off later, in relatively minor and unimporant ways. Maester Aemon (Targaryen) mentions that the last few dragons were weak and small, due to being raised in a castle, not their natural environment.*
>
> *However, it is my interpretation that those dragons were not (just) weak because of the castle environment (look at how much Danaerys' dragons have grown in the dungeons); but that this somehow ties in to the presence of magic. In aCoK, it is mentioned that "the glass candles are burning again", which is an indication of the resurgence of magic.*
>
> *This seems to coincide nicely with the dragon births, re-emergence of white walkers, the Fire Lord's miracles, etc. This also indirectly means that magic must have waned at some point in the past (otherwise it couldn't be a resurgence). As dragons are magical creatures, they may have been more prone to extinction after the magic "died down" (or whatever you want to call it), which may have expressed itself as dragons being weak and small as they have no magic to feed off (and people wrongly attributed it to the castle environment due to coinciding events).*

If Danaerys hadn't hatched the dragon eggs, and another 700 years would have gone by without any dragons, they would presumably have been assumed to be a myth, as much as the white walkers currently are.

---

Maybe slightly in support of your hopes of seeing more dragons:

I'm not sure if the books have confirmed/denied this; but it is maybe possible for the white walkers to bring dead dragons back to life. We've seen them do it for humans, giants and horses.
Unless the books have already confirmed it to be impossible; it should be possible to resurrect dragons.

Comment: Worth noting that Maester Aemon Targaryen says that the last dragon were very small and weak like puppies as they weren't meant for castle life

Comment: @LiquidSame: Daenerys' dragons have thrived in the dungeons though, as they have grown considerably larger between Dany imprisoning them and Tyrion removing their shackles. The strength (and size) of the dragons may be connected to the reawakening of magic. It is mentioned that "[glass candles](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Glass_candle) are burning again", which is an indication of the resurgence of magic. It also seems to coincide with the resurgence of white walkers, the advent of winter, Daenerys' fire resistance and the birth of her dragons (and arguably the Fire Lord's miracles).

Comment: 1st - Daenerys is not fire resistant. It's been said many times by the show runners. The thing with the dragon eggs was a one time thing. 2nd - I'm talking generations of dragons bred in castles, not just a few weeks/month. 3rd - Maybe. I do not know about the whole magic stuff. I was just bringing back that Aemon quote.

Comment: 1 Rephrase my previous statement by "whatever means that currently prevent Dany from burning". This includes excessively hot water (S1, the bath) and surviving fires that would kill a normal human (Drogo's burning, killing the Khals in Vaes Dothrak). This argument is semantical. 2 Fair enough, but I do still think this is related to magic more than _only_ environmental circumstances. 3 The Aemon quote is interesting for sure. I thought you were referencing it to contradict my answer; but it is relevant information as to the dragons of old.

Comment: "The Targaryen dragons were all but killed in a war that broke out between the Targaryens themselves" I was targeting this statement specifically. Your answer is good otherwise and I have nothing to say against it

Comment: @LiquidSame: My statement was based on an Alt Shift X video where he lists the dragons and how they died. I can't check for sure since I'm at work, but I think it was [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5I1jTJ9sYeA). Nonetheless, thanks for the addition! :)

Comment: As you can see he lists the dragons used by the Targaeryens to take and keep the throne. Nobody probably cared about the pecker-sized dragons that were born during the end era of the Targaeryens. (Also this is from the books and we know the show runners tend to deviate from them). All in all, interesting chat, have a nice day.

Comment: @Flater the books have not made a statement either way about Dragon Zombies or Warg Dragons.  There is a debate among fans whether or not they would be able to rise from the dead, or as 'magical creatures' are exempt from this.